# Скрыть строку таблицы исходя из текста и значения используя JS

Tags: javascript

Есть большая таблица с инпутами. Нужно при нахождении в соответствующей строке текста "Сортировка в разделе" и отсутствия значения в инпуте - скрыть данную строку. А если в инпуте есть значение, то она должна отображаться. Каким образом это возможно реализовать?

Пример кода:

```
<tr class="bx-in-group" id="tr_PROPERTY_487">
            <td class="adm-detail-valign-top adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">Сортировка в разделе "Товары недели [1968]":</td>
            <td width="60%" class="adm-detail-content-cell-r"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="nopadding" width="100%" id="tb68e701d72e69eddd13036f785eb247f3"><tbody><tr><td><input name="PROP[487][1278200]" value="100" size="30" type="text"><br></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
        </tr>
<tr class="bx-in-group" id="tr_PROPERTY_491">
            <td class="adm-detail-valign-top adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">Сортировка в разделе "Подарки на 23 февраля [1715]":</td>
            <td width="60%" class="adm-detail-content-cell-r"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="nopadding" width="100%" id="tbcc5a13764128559899cd006075fa2009"><tbody><tr><td><input name="PROP[491][n0]" value="" size="30" type="text"><br></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tdDesc = document.querySelectorAll('.desc');
const tdInps = document.querySelectorAll('td input');
const reg = /Сортировка в разделе/gi;

[...tdDesc].forEach((e, i) => {
  if(tdInps[i].value.length === 0 && reg.test(e.textContent)) {
    e.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="bx-in-group" id="tr_PROPERTY_487">
            <td class="adm-detail-valign-top adm-detail-content-cell-l desc" width="40%">
              Сортировка в разделе "Товары недели [1968]":
            </td>
            <td width="60%" class="adm-detail-content-cell-r">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="nopadding" width="100%" id="tb68e701d72e69eddd13036f785eb247f3">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input name="PROP[487][1278200]" value="100" size="30" type="text"><br>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bx-in-group" id="tr_PROPERTY_491">
          <td class="adm-detail-valign-top adm-detail-content-cell-l desc" width="40%">
            Сортировка в разделе "Подарки на 23 февраля [1715]":
          </td>
          <td width="60%" class="adm-detail-content-cell-r">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="nopadding" width="100%" id="tbcc5a13764128559899cd006075fa2009">
              <tbody>
                <tr> 
                  <td>
                    <input name="PROP[491][n0]" value="" size="30" type="text"><br>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только есть одна проблема - если подряд идут нескольтко инпутов с нулевым value, то скрываются они только через одного. Как можно сделать, чтобы скрывались все?